# Google Apps Script: Typescript instead of Javascript 'in' style tags for a web app

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, web-applications, transpiler

I want to develop in typescript instead of plain javascript for the code that gets sent to the user's browser. I am using the CL tool clasp to push my local files to my project.

I have three .ts files:

```
Code.ts        -- Server Side Code
types.ts       -- Mixed between both ends
IndexScript.ts -- Only meant for the browser.
```

In my JavaScript.html file, I want to have the following since without it the file is getting large:

```html
<script src='jquery URL'></script>
<script src='<unknown>'></script>
```

and then template it in with `<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>`.

I'm not sure what to put for the src tag.
My problem is that clasp transforms all the ts files to gs files. How can I use typescript + JQuery for my front end and share types from a separate file between both ends?

I tried to just transpile these files with typescript and it keeps causing naming collisions with clasp.

If I don't transpile I end up with this error:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '__esModule' of object '#' (line 2, file "IndexJavascript")

Comment: Just make your types a type declaration file - there is no benefit to make it a proper source file. Then ensure it's excluded from CLASP via the .claspignore file. As for a separate JS file for your frontend, the only way is to use a bundler (alternative is to save the frontend JS as HTML files wrapped into script tags, then you can include them as described by the docs, but that's troublesome and also requires a build step)

Comment: @Oleg Thanks. Based on your comment I'll found this resource promising :https://blog.gsmart.in/single-page-apps-vue-bootstrap-on-google-apps-script/